# Sitecore Azure package installation

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-azure

I am installing Sitecore Azure 8 from inside Sitecore using Admin account. Its keep installing the package taking a long time. Is there any alternate for this?

Comment: Are you able to install any other smaller packages?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you are trying to install the 'Sitecore Azure 8.0 rev. 150522.zip' Sitecore Installation Package that never finishes and always shows the 'Installing' progress bar in Installation Wizard application.

If yes, make sure your Sitecore XP 8.0 installation has valid connection to MongoDB instance.  If it does not have, a bunch of Sitecore Client functionality might work incorrectly, including Installation Wizard application.

Comment: Thanks Oleg,

Yes, it shows in progress continuously. If i don't want to use MongoDB then what can i do? Is there any other installation package available?

Comment: Sitecore XP 7.5 and 8.0 require MongoDB for Sitecore Analytics (aka Sitecore xDB). However, you can disable it using the techniques described in the following article: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/296641

Technically you can unzip the package and manually copy-past files from it, as well as deserialize items.

Comment: Please note that Sitecore Azure module version 8.0 rev. 150522 requires xDB Cloud Edition: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/880886

There is no way to deploy just a flat CMS without Analytics features.

Comment: I have installed mongodb and again tried installing Sitecore Azure package , now its throwing error: "The installation failed.
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: innerItem
For more information see the Sitecore log.
Try one of the following options:
Retry the installation"

Comment: Can you please share a correlated full error message with a stack trace from Sitecore Log file? Otherwise, I can only try to guess why it failed.

Comment: Log message: Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.System\Logging | Errors Logged / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters, Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.System\IO | File Watcher Events / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters, Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.System\Exceptions | Exceptions Thrown / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters, Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.System\Reflection | Objects Not Created / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters

Comment: Does not looks like this is the reason of why the installation failed. Could you please reproduce the issue again and share the entire Sitecore Log file? You can place it to any cloud drive such as OneDrive or Google Drive and post a link here.